# Can't run RSelenium rsDriver in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rselenium

So I want to have a shiny app that has a button. When that button is clicked I want to use Selenium to scrape some information from some website.
This is my sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(RSelenium)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button","CLICK ME")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$button,{
    driver = rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
    driver$client$navigate("http://www.google.ca")
    Sys.sleep(5)
    driver$server$stop()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

On my local computer, this works fine. However, on `shinyapps.io` I get the following log message:

Selenium message:

> Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default
>   location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no
>   binary flag set on the command line

I thought the problem might be that their system doesn't have a browser. So I tried to do:

```
system("sudo apt-get install firefox")
```

before starting the Selenium part but it required password since `sudo` and I don't know it.

Thanks for any help.